# Updating one field in model using MVC 3 and EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, automapper

`Model` class

```
public class product : BaseModel
    {
        [key] public string id { get; set; }
        [Required] public string title { get; set; }
        [Required] public bool valid { set; get; }
        public decimal discount { get; set; }
        public string summery { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
    }
```

in `View` I just need update `title` column , 
here is model code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()){
 @Html.HiddenFor(o => o.id);
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
 Title: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.title)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title)
}
```

in `Controller` , `product` lost other values except `id` and `title`

according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154120/update-single-property-on-ef4-entity-without-having-have-hidden-fields) one of the best solution is creating helper class for this specific form and use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map the helper to original model . but in my case ( over 60 models ) takes extra resources to implement helper classes. is there any better solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> in Controller , product lost other values except id and title

That's normal. What did you expect? Those are the only fields you have included in your HTML `<form>` so those are the only things you could ever hope to get back in your controller action.  That's how HTML works. Don't expect miracles, ASP.NET MVC won't just automagically set some values to the other fields of your model even if you haven't included them in the form POST.

Of course you could use the `id` that you received from the request to query your datastore and retrieve the corresponding model and do the respective processing on it.

So:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(int id)
{
    var product = db.Products.Where(x => x.Id == id);
    if (!TryUpdateModel(product))
    {
        // validation failed => redisplay the view
        return View(model);
    }

    // at this stage the product variable will be updated with the title
    // property coming from the view and all other properties staying untouched
    // => you could persist the changes back to the database
    // I don't remember the syntax of this EF stuff - go read the manual
    // of how to persist the changes of this "product" instance back to the context
    // As far as I remember it was something like "db.SaveChanges" or something.

    ...

    // after a successfull UPDATE redirect in order to follow good practices of the
    // Redirect-After-Post pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get
    return RedirectToAction("Success");
}
```

---

Be careful though with this approach though. **I do not recommend it**. An attacker could potentially set any properties like this by sending a specially crafted request. You should never pass your domain models to your views. You should always use view models.

In order to protect against those mass-injection attacks you should keep a list of properties that are actually allows to be updated from the view:

```
// ... only update the title property from the view
if (!TryUpdateModel(product, new[] { "title" }))
```

Now only the `title` property will be updated by the default model binder.

---

The actual solution I recommend is to use a view model of course (I can't keep rep[eating and stressing on this fact in the gazillions of answers I provide here on StackOverflow and I still see people using those EF autogenerated domain models in their views):

So, yeah, define a view model, what does it cost you? A <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> on your Models folder and then:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Was it so difficult?

And then navigate to your NuGet console and type: `Install-Package AutoMapper`. Then headaway to your `Application_Start` in `Global.asax` and define a mapping between your view model and your domain model (Actually it's better to later externalize your mapping in AutoMapper Profiles):

```
// gosh this EF crap generates lowercase classes => it sucks so badly
// and violates all C# conventions
Mapper.Map<ProductViewModel, product>();
```

and finally your controller action becomes:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(ProductViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var product = db.Products.Where(x => x.Id == id);
    Mapper.Map<ProductViewModel, product>(model, product);

    // at this stage the product variable will be updated with the title
    // property coming from the view and all other properties staying untouched
    // => you could persist the changes back to the database
    // I don't remember the syntax of this EF stuff - go read the manual
    // of how to persist the changes of this "product" instance back to the context
    // As far as I remember it was something like "db.SaveChanges" or something.

    ...

    // after a successfull UPDATE redirect in order to follow good practices of the
    // Redirect-After-Post pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get
    return RedirectToAction("Success");
}
```

Comment: so the answer is load the data from database and update all columns manually ?

Comment: No absolutely not, updating them manually would be insane. I would use the `TryUpdateModel` method that relies on the default model binder as shown in my answer.

Comment: One of the dangers with this approach is that a user could formulate form elements with the names of other properties of the model and surreptitiously update model properties that you did not intent to be updated. Eg. They pass it a post value with the name Discount and set it to 100 and it will update your discount property of your model even if you did not intend for them to do this. It is better to pass a view model with the properties you need to update.

Comment: thank you Darin, I really be happy when see your avatar in answers

Comment: @MichaelGattuso, that's absolutely true. This attack is called mass-property-assignment. It's one of the dangers when people do not follow good practices and do not use view models. I have updated my answer to talk a little about it.