# MVC 3, how not to display some Model Columns for editing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have my DB tables with created_date column and it works fine adding new record because I just set it by

```
 DateTime.Now
```

My problem is when I edit a record, it throws an error,

> SqlDateTime overflow because the created_date value is '1/1/0001'

I tried displaying created_date as a hidden field and it worked.
Is it possible not to add created_date in my form?

Comment: I found the solution here :
Hope it helped others too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154120/update-single-property-on-ef4-entity-without-having-have-hidden-fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I'll answer this great question I would like to thank you for posting.

You must manually code your EDIT/UPDATE Controller to prevent to save the null field..

This is the sample of manually coding of update model. In order to fill the null field you need to get the old value from the database.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult UpdateAction(Model model)
    {
        // Get the current values of model
        var _oldModel = db.GetModel(model.Id);

        // Specify or change only the field that is needed to Update

        _oldModel.property1 = model.property1;

        db.Model.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's required to add the created_date column as a hidden to the view. When you don't add the hidden, the controller will probably receive default value. Perhaps the type of your field is DateTime, so  '1/1/0001' is beyond its range. if you change the type to Datetime2 it will accept  '1/1/0001'.

--------------Update------------------------

I reproduced the problem, I think the best way is to put the hidden field in the view. Because when the view returns the model to the controller it sends all of the fields and if one field is missing it must be null. But because your column is not nullable the view sends '1/1/0001', and this value is not acceptable for Datetime.

Comment: But if i change the type to Datetime2 and accept '1/1/0001', it will overwrite the original created_dt when i edit the record. am I right?

Comment: I don't understand why the created_datewould be reqired. If you don't require it as a parameter to the Action Method. If you need to model-bind, MVC will happily pass along an Entity object with a null. And EF would assume its not updated.

Comment: Yes you're right Nikko, I didn't see your update at first. In edit view you are not required to write the hidden otherwise you want to change the value. Do you fill the field while you are creating the record?

Comment: I'm sorry i'm new to mvc and dont quite understand your suggestions.
when created_dt is not on my view, its value becomes '1/1/0001' when i save the form, how should i do that?

Comment: You said that this happens when you want to edit the record, so you must have create a record before. When you created the record, did you fill the column?

Comment: yes i did, i set its value with Datetime.Now before adding the record.

Comment: It' odd!! Did you check the returned post value in the post action of controller before saving?

Comment: Its value is '1/1/0001' for the passed model on my post action, because it is not on my view.

Comment: As I mention in my update above, hidden field is the best way for your case.

Comment: Well i guess, i'll just have to put a hidden on my form.